# How to create a Database on Blockchain and retrieve it after applying some operation and constraints on the data of tables?

Tags: blockchain, database

I want to create a database on Blockchain which gets input from a HTML form and add a tuple to table on Blockchain on each submission.The Tuples on Blockchain will be sorted by applying some operations on it and constraints of visibility of data for certain period of time. I had tried almost all available on internet but no platform provides such functionality and i can't find any relevant tutorials for the same.

Answer (score 2):

That makes no sense at all. The blockchain is not a database or a place where you store arbitrary data. The few bytes you may try to weasel in will be very expensive, so your application will be useless.

You're following "blockchain" buzzword hype sales talk that does not make sense and is simply a lie. Don't fall for it.

Look to MySQL or PostgresSQL or NoSQL or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The blockchain is not for sorting data or other forms of "functionality." That is a waste of (expensive) block chain resources, and that's why "no platform provides such functionality."

The blockchain can be used for storing a *reference* to your data using an identifier such as a hash total. That's where the "retrieval" part comes in.

In other words, do your calculations elsewhere, store the results elsewhere, and then it (might) make sense to post a reference on the blockchain to the data. But not the actual data itself.

Answer (score -1):

It is not good approach at all, but you can do so.

Currently good described methods if you use google:

1. OP return code
2. P2SH

Both approaches are different and both are well covered.

But as I mentioned before, it is not good approach to store data into blockchain, at least not into blockchains desinged to be digital currency.

Maybe best approach that you could do is to use testnet/regtest for your tests.

You could also fork any blockchain project (of the coin you like) and change it's parameters, like ie. max amount of P2SH addresses. With that you would have your own chain, configured for data storage the way you want to have and you could experiment then, whatever it is, ie. storing to any available blockchain TXID of your chain or whatever you want. If your tests go well and you have something useable, I would suggest you to start separate project with that.

Other users did suggest already some projects that you should look into, as they have the approach to store data using blockchain technology.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Try Bigchaindb.com or you will need to use mongo.db with a blockchain layer. I don't know your background but I would guess you will need some top-notch programmers to do this for you.